# How to remove action event after key pressed in a text field?

Tags: java, swing, keyevent, actionevent

I have a text field and mapped the enter key with an action to that text field. After enter key press, How can I remove that key event for press enter key in the text field?

Comment: Insert your code and/or example

Comment: Why?  `JTextField` already responds to Enter via the `ActionListener` and `Action` APIs

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: I have two separate components, I can only use this method to access the component reference. XXXmodule.getView() : JComponent, I want to add enter key listener to  components inside the parent component. How can it possible?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.  3) This sounds like an XY problem.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) But I agree with previous comment .. 'Why?'.

Comment: @SrishiyamalanRatnavel No, you don't want to add a key listener, you want to use an ActionListener or Action for text fields

Answer (score 0):

> After enter key press, How can I remove that key event for press enter key in the text field?

```
textField.removeActionListener(...);
```